# Fill NAs with condition

Tags: r

Hi I have a data frame

```
status       Value  
OFF           22
ON            34
OFF           NA
ON            NA
OFF           22
ON            12
ON            NA
```

I am trying to replace NA value with previous non-NA value when my condition matches i.e  IF NA found where status is 'ON' then replace with previous non-NA if status is ON

```
df$required= ifelse(df$status='ON'& is.na(df$value),
                               na.locf(df$value,na.rm=F),df$value)
```

> Error: unexpected ',' in "

```
status       Value    required
OFF           22        22
ON            34        34
OFF           NA        NA
ON            NA        34
OFF           22        22
ON            12        12
ON            NA        12
```

Any modification would be appriciated,Thanks

Comment: Just do `df$Value[df$status == 'ON'] <- na.locf(df$Value[df$status == 'ON'])`

Comment: First thing, `==` should be used for comparison, you are using `=`.

Comment: Thanks Ronak, to figure out my small mistake

Comment: Thanks Sotos ...

Comment: @Sotos You mean from `na.locf` coming from  `library(zoo)` right?

Comment: @amonk yes. you are correct